# why npm install no needed package?

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

I want to know what make **"npm install"** install @angula  from this package.json dependecies ?

```
"dependencies": {
    "@trust/webcrypto": "^0.9.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "civic-sip-api": "^1.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "ethereumjs-testrpc": "^6.0.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "gun": "^0.9.993",
    "ipfs": "^0.28.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.1",
    "md5": "^2.2.1",
    "orbit-db": "^0.19.7",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "sha3": "^1.2.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.0",
    "socketio-jwt": "^4.5.0",
    "uport-connect": "^0.7.2",
    "web3": "^0.20.6"
  },
```

after running "npm install" in the project folder I got some non needed package such as **@angular, @angular-devkit, @ngtools**

Comment: Packages have dependencies. It's up to the mantainer to define them. Installing one package may lead to 1,000 packages to be installed. They may not be needed by you directly, but they most likely are used by the package as a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are dependencies of each module.  If you open up each module it has a package.json with the dependencies of the installing module.